# Microsoft CRM Report Authoring Extension Issue

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to create SSRS report for MS CRM, I am unable to find Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch connection type or how to enable it, while searching over the internet, I found I have to install Microsoft CRM Report Authoring Extension. I installed the extension & now I am facing this issue (See the below pic).

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHPHa.jpg)

My PC (windows 10) contains these software (may it help) :-

1- Visual Studio 2015.

2- SQL Server 2012.

3- SQL Server Data Tool (SSDT).

4- Business Intelligence (Analyst Services, Integration Services, Reporting Services)  .

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated and acknowledged.

Thanks ...

Comment: did you click "Details"?

Comment: Yes I did, it's useless, it's just says :-

       
Some of the required components are missing. For more information, click Details.

For a list of the required components, see the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Report Authoring Extension (with SQL Server Data Tools support) download page (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=671952).

Comment: it's not useless, that page says that you need VS 2012 or VS 2010, you have VS 2015

Comment: @GuidoPreite do you recommend to install VS 2012 in the same machine that has VS 2015 or another machine ?, because I will do a test as you notified me about VS versions . Thanks alot..

Comment: you can install in the same machine, in mine I have 2010,2012,2013,2015

Comment: @GuidoPreite Yes I installed VS 2012 and now it's working fine, Thanks alot .

Comment: YES I agree with you Majed,  its USELESS.   it doesn't tell you WHAT components are missing.    thanks Guido, but that page definitely does NOT tell you that you need VS2012.. it basically gives you an error but doesn't tell what component it was checking for.